# The delta function as an eigenfunction of the position operator explanation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, observables, dirac-delta-distributions

> $\delta (\textbf{r})$  can be interpreted as a wavefunction. [...] It is non-vanishing only for $\textbf{r}=0$. [...] $\delta(\textbf{r})$ is an eigenfunction of the position operator with eigenvalue zero.

How is this last statement true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this last statement true?

On the position basis, the (1-D) position operator is multiplication by $x$.

A well known property of the Dirac delta distribution is

$$f(x)\delta(x) = f(0)\delta(x)$$

since $\delta(x)$ is zero everywhere except $x=0$ were it has unit area.

Thus

$$x\delta(x) = 0\delta(x)$$

So, operating on $\delta(x)$ with the position operator returns $\delta(x)$ multiplied by zero, which is to say that $\delta(x)$ is an eigenfunction (distribution) of the position operator with eigenvalue zero.

Answer (score 4):

For that to be true you will have to go beyond the Hilbert space and consider the *rigged* Hilbert space, that is the Hilbert space plus distributions. Hence this can be made formal if you identify Dirac's bras and kets with the (anti)linear rigged Hilbert space.

In more intuitive terms, the delta function $\delta(\mathbf r)$ can be realised as limits of a normalised gaussian centred at $\mathbf r = 0$, where you assume that the width is shrinking on to that point (indeed this would give you an approximate eigenvector of the position operator with eigenvalue 0). Observe that the $\delta$ function as it is is already normalised in the so-called $\delta$-normalisation.